# How to dynamically add text box and retrieve the values in it

Tags: codeigniter, session

I have created a log in page with session library,

so my question is, how do i access the session after a user logs in when i link through web pages.

do i have to use @session_start(); on every webpage i link? I am using  link.

I have this controller after validating the log in details:

```
function verify_account()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $query = $this->user_model->validate();

        if($query)
        {   
            $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            $data['main_content']= 'homepage';
            $this->load->view('includes/templates',$data);
        }

        else
        {   
            $this->index();
        }
    }
```

If my question wasn't clear enough, The problem is, after i logged in, the homepage displays which user i have logged on to but when i click a link,(Would need to go through a controller function first to load the templates) so how do i retrieve the recently created session and pass it on to the page i link?

P.S. I cant ask any questions so im stuck to editing my posted questions. Posted block :(. sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: You should describe:  What do you expect to happen? What happen istead?

Comment: What's your problem with it?  It works fine... http://jsfiddle.net/WrVyb/

Comment: @Archer I have edited my post above, should i edit the javascript and change it to

function addtext(){
Code goes here
}

and just add onclick events on the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a script include with script inside the tag.  The inner script gets ignored.  Change your script to this...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 2;

        $("#addButton").click(function () {
            if (counter > 10) {
                alert("Only 10 textboxes allowed");
                return false;
            }
            $('<div/>',{'id':'TextBoxDiv' + counter}).html(
                $('<label/>').html( 'Textbox #' + counter + ' : ' ))
                    .append( $('<input type="text">').attr({'id':'textbox' + counter,'name':'textbox' + counter}) )
                    .appendTo( '#TextBoxesGroup' );
            counter++;
        });

        $("#removeButton").click(function () {
            if (counter == 1) {
                alert("No more textbox to remove");
                return false;
            }
            counter--;
            $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
        });

        $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
            }
            alert(msg);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Look at the top.  There's the script include (for jQuery), and that tag is closed, with another tag for the script in your page.

Here's a working example...

http://jsbin.com/AVuXuSo/1/

Comment: So the first script was for jquery while this code is javascript.. i didnt notice that.. silly me. or am i wrong? care to explain. i want to understand..

Comment: Easy mistake to make.  Glad I could help :)

Comment: Could you please edit your post in segments and show me how the code works? basically the flow of the code.

Comment: I don't see there's much I could do to help, to be honest, after already tidying the code and making it more readable.  It *is* in sections, identified by the click event handlers.

Comment: No worries. i can definitely figure it out myself when i get the time